# Module File Upload

Tags: 7

I am working on a module and I am trying to add an upload box for an MP3 file.  I cannot seem to get it working no matter what I try to do.  I have looked at file_save_upload and I am not having any luck.  Below is my form code.  Could someone point me in the right direction for the file upload process?

```
$form['background_audio_file'] = array(
  '#type'=> 'file',
  '#title' => t('Upload File'),
  '#description' => t('Please select your file to be uploaded'),
);

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save Changes'),
);
```

The form is working great I just cant seem to find a good example and makes sense for uploading a simple mp3 file.  This is D7 btw.

Thanks in advance.

Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than worry about moving/saving the file yourself you could use the [`managed_file`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) element type and let Drupal do it for you:

```
function mymodule_some_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['background_audio_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Upload File'),
    '#description' => t('Please select your file to be uploaded'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://audio-files' 
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save Changes'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_some_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // The file is automatically uploaded and saved in the default
  // validation process so you just need to load the file object at this point,
  // mark that you want to keep it, and save it again.
  // The file ID is contained in the $form_state['values'] array
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['background_audio_file']);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
}
```

Uploading files using this method has the added benefit of a reference to them being added to the `file_managed` table so they can be managed with the system at a later date if needs be.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that does help!  Thank you!  I have implimented the code you provided and I get this error when I try to upload a file:

    Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uri in     file_save() (line 573 of /Users/jtharpe/Overflow_Dev/includes/file.inc).

Comment: Never mind I figured that part above up however after uploading my file I get the error: Only files with the following extensions are allowed: jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp.  <-- Is there a way to add MP3 to this so I can upload my file?'

Comment: There is, see [this post](http://drupal.org/node/546146) for more details